# How can I use Rosemary bulbs in cooking?

Tags: herbs

I pulled out a rosemary plant today and found a number of bulbs amongst the root system.   Can these be used for cooking, such as with a roast lamb?  How?

I also have lots of leaves, so if the bulbs are no good I don't need to use them but I thought it was interesting to try.

[image: rosemary bulb]

Comment: I don't know, but I would say don't eat them unless you get an answer to the contrary!

Comment: This looks like massive root nodules, ie a symbiosis with bacteria. Do you have other plants nearby that could, in particular legumes?

Comment: The only other plants nearby are gardenia, murraya hedge and a climbing weed.

Comment: The whole premise of this question is wrong but I'm unable to delete it.

Comment: @WW. You are unable to delete the question, because it has an upvoted answer. [That’s in the SE design](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions). And you know what? Even a question that started with a false premise is useful - as can be seen by the upvotes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don’t know what you dug up, but *rosemary doesn’t have bulbs* so **do not eat this!**

For plant id questions (which is outside the scope of this site), I recommend our sister site Gardening SE.

Comment: They smell like rosemary, perhaps due to being so close.

Comment: They could be a reaction to a plant infection. Some insect larvae can produce reactions like this as they live inside the infected part of the plant.